# Javascript Functions within Array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to print out the [ith] element of the array with the [ith] function's argument? for example, print out the returned value of 2nd element of the array with input (3) as function's argument

```
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `puzzlers[1](puzzlers[2]);`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge What would be the result of `(function() { a * a + 4 } - 3)` ? O.o

Comment: @Andreas: Knowing ECMAScript, it wouldn't surprise me if that actually has a defined value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag There is one, but I doubt that `NaN` is the desired output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are looking for. I assume that you want to call the `i`th function passing `j` as an argument.

To access the `i`th element of an `Array`, you use the square brackets post-around-fix indexing operator `[]` and pass the index inside the square brackets, which looks like this: `ary[idx]`. To call a function, you use the round parentheses post-around-fix function call operator `()` and pass the argument inside the round parentheses, which looks like this: `func(arg)`.

Like this:

```
puzzlers[2](3);
```

There's really nothing puzzling about this, if you understand what an array is and what a function is.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I understand the use of [] which is for the element of the array, however I didn't know how to execute the function with a specific argument within an array. I tried puzzlers([2](3))--got an error saying puzzlers wasn't a function but this was close though , and puzzlers[2.(3)]  in JS Bin but it didn't work. Thanks again :)

Comment: Programming languages, even ones with such quirks as ECMAScript / JavaScript, are usually much more logical than you think. Just lean back and think about the atomic pieces and how to put them together. How do access an array? Put brackets after it. What is the array in this case? `puzzlers`, ergo: `puzzlers[2]`. How do you call a function? Put parentheses after it. What is the function in this case? It's `puzzlers[2]`. What does it look when you put parentheses after it? `puzzlers[2](3)`. There you go, all things you already know before asking this question, you were just intimidated.

Comment: I thought puzzlers [2](3) would yield (function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); }(2)) which I thought was wrong since I am used to accessing non functional elements of array

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for this, but the question is a bit cryptic.

```js
var puzzlers = [
  function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
  function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
  function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function(a) { return a % 5; }
];

var secondFunction = puzzlers[1];
var result = secondFunction(3);
alert(result);

//or short

alert(puzzlers[1](3));
```